# Django show menu dynamically

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

Hii I m working on demo , and i have a problem is my program, is that i want to fetch all the menu from my batabase. my issue is that the menu is in the row and the click event is same , so want to extract all the menus.

models.py

```
class MainMenu(models.Model):
menu_type = models.CharField(max_length=32)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % (self.menu_type)
```

context_processor.py

```
def menu(request):
menu = MainMenu.objects.all()
return {'menu':menu}
```

base.html

```
                    <li><ul>
                    {% for m in menu %}
                    <li><a href="#">{{m.menu_type}}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

My menu are Showing like

```
Home
AboutUS
```

But i want them like

```
Home  AboutUs
```

Answer (score 0):

use **css** `ul li{display: inline;}`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<li>
  <ul>
    {% for m in menu %}
      <li style="display: inline;"><a href="#">{{m.menu_type}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</li>
```